# Fortran fomat statement with highest precision in the system

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran77

Someone wanting less precision would write

```
999    format ('The answer is x = ', F8.3)
```

Others wanting higher output precision may write

```
999 format ('The answer is x = ', F18.12)
```

Thus it totally depends on what the user desires. What is the format 
statement that exactly matches the precision used in the calculation?
(Note, this may vary from system to system)

Comment: List directed IO, `write (*, *)`, should automatically provide the precision of the types in the list. But you give up control of the layout of the output. Is there a guarantee that the values can be read back in with exact recovery of the values??

Comment: no doubt a compiler dependent thing, but list directed write gives me a tad less precision than required to read the value back in without loss ( looks like * gives f15.6 for a single precision value of order 1, where f15.7 is needed. )

Comment: @Jagte FYI stuffing a string in a format statent is old school. I hope you don't think its required.   write(\*,\*)'The answer is',x is likely all you need, unless you really mean to be retentive about maybe losing one digit precision or you really need precise control over spacing.

Comment: How would one go about determining what precision was used in the calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a difficult question because you request "the precision of the calculation", which depends on so many factors. For example: if I solve f(x)=0 via Newton's method to a tolerance of 1E-6, would you want a format with seven digits?

On the other hand, if you mean the "highest precision attainable by the type" (e. g., double or single precision) then you can simply find the corresponding epsilon (machine eps, or precision) and use that as the format flag. If epsilon is 1E-15, then you can use a format flag that does not have more than 16 digits.

In Fortran you can use the EPSILON(X) function to get this number (the answer will depend on the type of X), the you can take the floor of the absolute value of the logarithm (base 10) of epsilon, and make that the number of decimals in your float representation.

For example, if epsilon is 1E-12, the log is -12, the abs is 12, and the floor is 12, so you want a format like 15.12F (12 decimals + 1 point + the zero + the sign = 15 places)

Comment: To do this automatically, you can `WRITE` the number you obtain from `EPSILON()` to a character and then concatenate that into a format statement.

Comment: @Arrieta, you are half way.. once you determine the required precision you need to also account for the magnitude of the number to get the exactly required number of decimals.   Lots of work to reinvent list directed formatting..

Comment: @George: I agree with you... I actually don't like my answer ;( I am proposing a hack which goes half-way. But I don't have more ideas ;(

Answer (score -1):

The problem with floating point numbers is that there is no precision as such: only significant digits.

For instance, if you are calculating longitudes in real*1, near the UK, you'd be accurate to 6 decimal places but if you were in Colorado Springs, it would only be accurate to 4 decimal places.  It would not make any sense to print the number in F format it is just rubbish after the 4th decimal place.

If you wish to print to maximum precision, print in E format.  Since it is always n.nn..nEnn, you get all the significant digits.

**Edit - user4050's query**
Try the following example

```
program main
   real intpart, multiplier
   integer ii

   multiplier = 1
   do ii = 1, 6
      intpart = 9.87654321
      intpart = intpart * multiplier
      print '(F15.7 E15.7 G15.8)', intpart, intpart, intpart
      multiplier = multiplier * 10
   end do
   stop
end program
```

What you will get is something like

```
      9.8765430  0.9876543E+01  9.8765430
     98.7654266  0.9876543E+02  98.765427
    987.6542969  0.9876543E+03  987.65430
   9876.5429688  0.9876543E+04  9876.5430 
  98765.4296875  0.9876543E+05  98765.430
 987654.3125000  0.9876543E+06  987654.31
```

Notice that the precision changes as the number gets bigger because a float only has 7 significant figures.

Comment: When this answer is comprehensible it is wrong.  A good working definition of the precision of a number stored or manipulated by a computer is the number of significant digits stored or manipulated.  Fortran's `e` edit descriptor can be used to write none, few, many or all of the significant digits of a `real`.  As for the comment about the relative accuracy of longitudes in the UK vs Colorado, I suppose you're stuck thinking in degrees -- change to radians.

Comment: When most people who use Fortran say precision, they mean decimal places.  The point is to use E format rather than F format to get the significant digits.  If F format is used, you may get all the significant digits, insufficient digits or you may get absolute rubbish.  Longitudes are just an example that everyone understands: it could be anything with a wide range.

Comment: @cup I am interested in your answer but I don't see how it's different than using the F format, you still need to specify the number of digits you want to print also in the E format, no?